# When using the Collection Info node, is there a way to transfer geo node attributes from instanced objects and use it?

Tags: collections, instances, geometry-nodes

[image]So I made a simple geometry node tree to create a tile with a hole. You can control the size of the hole (X and Y) from within modifier properties panel.
Then I made a another geo tree that instances the collection of these tiles. Is there a way to use size of the hole (the X and Y values of the first Geo node tree) for example to instance
cubes the exact size of the hole at the same spot of the other instances?

Thanks

[image]

I have an update, if I use a REalize instances node, I get the two attributes visible in my spreadsheet but I have no idea how to use these values in my node editor. There is no Attribute node to just type "xx" or "yy" like we have a value node,a string node, or a material node. Solution for this one maybe?

Comment: in your "special case" why don't you just use one instance which makes the plane and your cylinder?

Comment: My actual specific case is more complicated than this. This was just an example I used to be able to explain what I needed more easily. I didn't use my specific example cause my node tree has more than 200 nodes. And there's 2 of them.
So? No solution?

Comment: I have answered on a very similar question some time ago, the only difference that it was about the curves instead of meshes. But the idea is the same. Does this answer your question? [How to pass individual values to each instance of the object generated with Geometry Nodes 3.0](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245666/how-to-pass-individual-values-to-each-instance-of-the-object-generated-with-geom)

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer". This will make it easier for others to see which path leads to the solution, and the question will no longer show as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to transfer geo node attributes from instanced objects and use it?

Yes, this is possible.

You would only have to pass the *Group Attributes* of your first node group to the *Group Input* of your second group.

(You have already done the first step in your example).

Then use the same identifiers in the *Group Input* of the *Geometry Nodes* where you instantiate these objects.

Once you convert the instances with the node `Realize Instances`, you can access these values with `Transfer Attributes` and process them accordingly.

[image]

*I have added a scale node here for better illustration, which of course you don't need.*

[image]